# WordPress Custom Taxonomy Term Meta Value

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I have created a Custom Taxonomy for Event Categories.

I have added a color picker form field in the category so all categories added can have a color associated with it.

I have the saved data in my **wp_termeta** table in the database:

```
meta_id = 1
term_id = 2 
meta_key = _category_color
meta_value = 8224e3 (hex color)
```

I am displaying the events in fullcalendar and I am trying to grab the color of the event taxonomy and use it for the event background color in the calendar.

I am using a php file for my JSON feed and already have all the events coming through in a WP_Query and looping them but I cant figure out how to grab the _category_color value from the term_meta.

```
$events = array();
$result = new WP_Query('post_type=event');

foreach($result->posts as $post) {

// To get the term ID I tried
$term = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'eventcategory' );
$term_vals = get_term_meta($term,'_category_color');

$events = array(
    'title'   => $post->post_title,
    'start'   => date( 'Y-m-d', $data['start-date'] ),
    'end'     => date( 'Y-m-d', $data['end-date'] ),
    'url'   =>  get_post_permalink($post->ID),
    'backgroundColor' => '#'.$term_vals["_category_color"][0],
    'allDay'  => false
    );

}

echo json_encode($events);
exit;
```

I am just making a mess with the code and cant figure out how to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out.

I was so close, yet, so far. I have commented the code to let you know how I figured it out.

```
$events = array();
$result = new WP_Query('post_type=event');

foreach($result->posts as $post) {

// I have to first get the Terms
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'choirboss_eventcategory' );

//Then I had to loop through the terms to get the term_id
if($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_id = $term->term_id;
    }
}

//Now I can grab my _category_color like this
$category_color = get_term_meta($term_id, '_category_color', true);

$events = array(
    'title'   => $post->post_title,
    'start'   => date( 'Y-m-d', $data['start-date'] ),
    'end'     => date( 'Y-m-d', $data['end-date'] ),
    'url'   =>  get_post_permalink($post->ID),
    'backgroundColor' => '#'.$category_color,
    'allDay'  => false
    );

}

echo json_encode($events);
exit;
```